# OpenCV 2.3.1 highgui crash on exit when using cvVideoWriter

Tags: c, opencv, crash, exit

recently I was recommended here on Stackoverflow to upgrade to OpenCV 2.3.1 in order to improve the results with `cvVideoWriter` (the last frame of a video was neither read/ written) and indeed with v.2.3.1 reading is okay but writing still is sort of a problem. Nevertheless I fixed this issue but couln't cope with another: my program will always crash when using the VideoWriter function. I've checked the cause and it turned out to be the new version of highgui (2.3.1) because if I use highgui210 instead no crash occurs (but the last frame issue of course). Does anyone know this problem and how to resolve it? Btw, I don't know if it is of any importance: I've followed the instructions on the following page to install OpenCV 2.3.1 on my system (I'm using VS 9 Express):

http://www.arunkumarr.co.in/site/index.php/articles/10-configuring-opencv-23-in-visual-studio-2008

Cheers
Stephan

Comment: Would love to see a minimal example that reproduces the problem you are facing. I'm using 2.3.1 without any problems for a long time.

Comment: I almost missed your comment as it appears above the first answer. Glad I didn't :D and now I just accidentally pushed the enter key so I can probably not edit and insert the code in time... will do so asap

Comment: Ok, leave a comment when you update the question so I can get back here and take another look.

Comment: sorry it took a while, had to remove a lot and put it into a txt file as it doesn't fit into the comment box. Here's the link  http://www.file-upload.net/download-4282308/code1.txt.html

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not a minimal example as I requested. It's imcomplete, horribly idented, it doesn't compile, and therefore it's impossible to tell what's wrong with it.

The fact that it crashes in the most recent OpenCV version doesn't necessarily mean that OpenCV has a problem: it may be that they finally did a decent implementation in a function that was doing practically nothing in previous versions.

The most appropriate course of action for you to take is: **write a minimal application that performs the core tasks that you are interested** at, which by reading your code it seems to be:

- **Read frames from a camera;**
- **Open a video writer to record the frames from the camera into the disk;**

Just these 2 tasks, it's that simple! Forget all the other stuff, `CreateAvi()`, `CloseAvi()`, `remove()`, and other functions that do not belong to OpenCV.

The simple application will demonstrate that OpenCV works, and that the problem you saw is probably caused by something else present in the code that was removed from this simple application.

This problem is not in OpenCV, it comes from the code you wrote.

**EDIT**:

Hello german fellow, I don't feel attacked by your questions nor I develop OpenCV. Now, the application below does what you should have done from the start. **It's a minimal example that uses OpenCV to read a video file, displays the frames on a window and then writes the frames to a new file on the disk**. It's simple, it works, and it demonstrates what I've been trying to tell you: the problem you observed is not caused by a bug in OpenCV 2.3.1. Enjoy:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main()
{   
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture("green_lantern_sample.avi");
    if (!capture)
    {
        printf("!!! cvCreateFileCapture failed\n");
        return -1; 
    }

    int frame_count = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
    int fps = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
    int video_w = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    int video_h = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    printf("* %d x %d\n", video_w, video_h);

    CvVideoWriter* writer = cvCreateVideoWriter("out.avi", 
                                                CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D'), 
                                                fps, 
                                                cvSize(video_w, video_h), 
                                                1);
    if (!writer)
    {
        printf("!!! cvCreateVideoWriter failed\n");
        return -1; 
    }

    cvNamedWindow("video");
    IplImage* frame = NULL;
    while (true)
    {        
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        if(!frame)
            break;

        cvWriteFrame(writer,frame);                 

        cvShowImage("video", frame);
        cvWaitKey(1);        
    }

    cvReleaseVideoWriter(&writer);
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    cvDestroyWindow("video");

    return 0;
}
```

Tested with OpenCV 2.3.1 on: VS 9 Express (Windows XP 32bits) and Fedora Linux (also 32 bits).

Comment: okay, first off Karl Philip, I misunderstood what you meant by minimal example. I'm German and I thought you meant small portion of my code (removing all unrelated stuff). Secondly OpenCV lacks certain capabilities when it comes to writing AVI. That I concluded from the many threads about this topic that can be found elsewhere. It almost sounds like you feel attacked ... are you an OpenCV programmer? If so, it certainly isn't my intention to draw a bad picture about the tool. I just asekd a question about writing avis.

Comment: as the avi is written (it's from a video-source, not from camera) and the result is readable (this only works for Xvid btw and last frame issue with writing still seems not to be resolved) and everything works fine until the end of the program I suppose it has something to do with highgui (especially if one considers the fact that the previous highgui version was ok, I don't think it's due to an additional implementation). Maybe a process is still active when the program stops, I don't know. To me it seems very strange that nothing AFTER writing the AVI indicates an error until the end.

Comment: I don't exclude of course that it's a mistake in my code but I think it's logical and not arrogant to believe that it's due to the new highgui as the previous highgui worked. I will try to find the error myself now and if I find something I'll let you know.   Cheers Stephan

Comment: Come back in 1 hour and I'll have something more concrete to share with you.

Comment: here's what the details tell (hadn't checked the windows error message before): Problemsignatur:
  Problemereignisname: APPCRASH
  Anwendungsname: name.exe
  Anwendungsversion: 0.0.0.0
  Anwendungszeitstempel: 4f8f0565
  Fehlermodulname: xvidvfw.dll
  Fehlermodulversion: 0.0.0.0
  Fehlermodulzeitstempel: 4a2bcd84
  Ausnahmecode: c0000005
  Ausnahmeoffset: 000098f4
  Betriebsystemversion: 6.0.6000.2.0.0.768.3
  Gebietsschema-ID: 1031

Comment: Zusatzinformation 1: 9905
  Zusatzinformation 2: 6275ca7140be90373e6481e85e89008d
  Zusatzinformation 3: a69a
  Zusatzinformation 4: 61cd78cce0497df023b282c925c2a69b

Lesen Sie unsere Datenschutzrichtlinie:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=50163&clcid=0x0407

Comment: so may be it's neither an OpenCV nor a program but an Xvid issue? This also happens with uncompressed videos though. Perhaps Xvid handles all the video processing?!

Comment: solved. Updated Xvid from version 1.3.1 to 1.3.2 and the crash miraculously vanished. sorry for the inconvience! Praise OpenCV :-)

Comment: Feel free to upvote my answer or select it as the official problem solver by clicking in the checkbox near it.

Comment: I'll upvote as you have really tried to help and thank you for the code. Although I don't need it (haven't changed a letter in my code) many others might find it very helpful. Best, Stephan    edit: unfortunately it tells me I don't have enough reputation (15) to vote.

Comment: Someday you will, there's no rush. Good luck and feel free to ask new questions in new threads.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the latest OpenCV available is 2.4 beta 2. Please try it, and check whether the problem still occurs.

But the problem may also be caused by a wrong config - check that all your paths (ENV variables, Visual Studio config, bin files, lib files and include dirs point to the correct OpenCV version)

Comment: hmm, the environment variables could be the cause as I wasn't able to follow step 4 on said page because I couldn't find the respective menu ''System Properties''. I thought it was because I use the Express version. Was my assumption wrong and I just overlooked it? Thanks for your help

Comment: I think I found the menu and added the path but it didn't change. Then I installed OpenCV 2.4 beta 2 but still the same issue. Maybe there's another way around?